# placing caption on the top  right or top left -

Tags: positioning, captions

I would like to have my captions as shown in the image below. I want them to appear on the TOP left of the image. I tried SideCap, but it puts them at the bottom of image.

[image]

Comment: Use `\sidecaptionvpos{<float type>}{<pos>}`. Say `\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}` should do the job. For figures the default is `b` i.e., bottom. Without a MWE it is difficult to get more details of your problem. If this does not solve the problem, pl add a MWE. Instead you can also use `floatrow` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Harish Kumar mentioned in his comment. you can use `\sidecaptionvpos` to control the vertical placement of the caption and the `innercaption` package option to place the captions right on left pages and left on right pages (as your example seems to show). In the following example I also used `\subcaptionbox` from the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package to place the subfigures; the `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces the images with black rectangles (do *not*use that option in your actual code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[innercaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}
\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{5.5cm}
  \subcaptionbox{A subfigure\label{fig:sub1}}{\includegraphics{name1}}\\
  \subcaptionbox{Another subfigure\label{fig:sub2}}{\includegraphics{name2}}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{\protect\lipsum[2]}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to control the spacing between the sidecaption and the figure? in my pdf's the caption is directly at the figure without any spacing...