# Horizontal positioning of sidecap figures

Tags: floats, positioning

I am using a little variation of the code provided by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47927/placing-caption-on-the-top-right-or-top-left),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}
\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{5.5cm}
  \subcaptionbox{figure 1 \label{fig:sub1}}{\includegraphics{name1}}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{\protect\lipsum[2]}
\end{SCfigure}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{5.5cm}
  \subcaptionbox{figure 2 \label{fig:sub1}}{\includegraphics{name2}}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{\protect\lipsum[2]}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

to generate these figures:

[image]

Is it possible to place these 2 figures side by side?

Comment: Isn't the current captioning redundant and confusing? Figure `1` is also labeled `(a)` and Figure `2` is also `(a)`. Should just the main caption remain?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you for your attention. In this case, the redundancy is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the [`hvfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) and [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) packages; the double labeling was kept (as requested in a comment to the question); depending on the actual images, some setting might need to be adjusted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\savebox\hvOBox{\parbox{3cm}{\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\par\captionof{subfigure}{Figure 1}}}
\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capWidth=0.45,%
capPos=r,%
capVPos=t,%
useOBox=true
]{figure}{}%
{An example of a caption vertically top aligned beside the image; two simple test images on a row}{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\savebox\hvOBox{\parbox{3cm}{\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\par\captionof{subfigure}{Figure 2}}}
\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capWidth=0.45,%
capPos=r,%
capVPos=t,%
useOBox=true
]{figure}{}%
{An example of a caption vertically top aligned beside the image; two simple test images on a row}{fig:testb}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler option with four `minipage`s and the `caption`/`subcaption` combo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par
  \captionof{subfigure}{Figure 1}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  \captionsetup[figure]{belowskip=0pt}
  \captionof{figure}{An example of a caption vertically top aligned beside the image; two simple test images on a row}
  \label{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par
  \captionof{subfigure}{Figure 2}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  \captionsetup[figure]{belowskip=0pt}
  \captionof{figure}{An example of a caption vertically top aligned beside the image; two simple test images on a row}
  \label{fig:testb}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]